# Double numeration invoice Odoo v8

Tags: odoo, invoice

I'm working for a company as a scholar. And they've asked me to implement an ERP to handle their invoices.

I've selected odoo coz its the only one I can somehow handle. Im not an expert developer and im even worse in ERP/Odoo.

The thing is, that the company has 2 different numeration mask(L2M000 & IW000) for invoices and i can just set one from the account module configuration.

I've tried many things and ive manage to get 2 different print pdf layouts, but i dont know how to set 2 different numeration masks.

Hope someone can help me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hello follow these steps to change Sequence numbers for desired apps.

You now have to activate Developer Mode to get access to the Technical sub menu within Settings, where all of the familiar administrative management menus are.

First, click the arrow next to the question mark inside the circle (this is found on the right hand side of the screen within the purple bar {Enterprise} or black bar {Community}), and select About.

[image]

Next, click Activate Developer Mode.

Finally, visit **Settings -> Technical --> Sequences and Identifiers --> Sequences.**

You will get options as shown below.

Then edit the one which you want to.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, i know how to do that. The thing is i want to get 2 different sequences. If I edit the one i have, i'm missing one again. I'm sorry, i dont c ur answer working or i might missunderstood it. In any way, thanks!

Comment: And i want to add this sequence to the invoice report. And thats what i dont know how to do it. Any idea?